# Should we report $\LaTeX$/MathJax issues in meta?

Tags: support, mathjax

Should we report $\LaTeX$/MathJax issues in meta?? If so here is something 
I recently found: The following code (edit to see it) effects the line break behaviour:

```
 \frac{\text{numerator}}\\\text{denominator missing, linebreak doesn't work}
```

$$
\frac{\text{numerator}}\\\Rightarrow\text{denominator was missing, line break doesn't work} \tag{1}
$$

```
 \frac{\text{numerator}}{\text{denominator}}\\\text{denominator present, linebreak works}
```

$$
\frac{\text{numerator}}{\text{denominator}}\\\Rightarrow\text{denominator present, line break works}\tag{2}
$$

Comment: Yes. Some of the MathJax developers roam around the meta site; and some of the bugs are due to faulty SE code. Both parties are roaming around this meta to find bug reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\cfrac` needs a denominator so it treats the first two backslash `\\` as the denominator, a backslash is always followed by a command (even if it is just a space), so what you did was define the denominator as a linebreak.

`$\frac{\text{numerator}}\\\text{denominator is a linebreak, text follows the fraction}`

is $$\cfrac {\text{numerator}}\\\text{denominator is a linebreak, text follows the fraction}$$ but since the backslash isn't define, one has to use `\backslash`, then  nothing appears in the denominator.

- but it changes if an additional backslash is added, like this

  `\frac{\text{numerator}}\ \\\text{denominator is a space, linebreak works}`

  and you get this

  $$\frac{\text{numerator}}\ \\\text{denominator is a space, linebreak works} $$
  which gives you what you want.

  Notice the space after the first backslash, it means that the denominator is just a space.
- Assuming there is no space

  `\frac{\text{numerator}}\\\\text{denominator is a linebreak, linebreak works but text doesn't}`

  or there is a space after the first two backslash

  `\frac{\text{numerator}}\\ \\text{denominator is a linebreak, linebreak works but text doesn't}`

  it treats the first two backslashes `\\` (a linebreak) as the denominator, and the last two `\\` as another linebreak, thus rendering the rest as non-formatted text and you get this

$$\frac{\text{numerator}}\\\\text{denominator is a linebreak, linebreak works but text doesn't} $$

- Now let's put the space after the first three backslash

  `\frac{\text{numerator}}\\\ \text{denominator is a linebreak,a space follows the fraction, and text works}`

  $$\frac{\text{numerator}}\\\ \text{denominator is a linebreak,a space follows the fraction, and text works}$$
- Let's put spaces between all backlashes

  `\frac{\text{numerator}}\ \ \ \text{denominator is a space, two spaces follow the fraction, and text works}`

$$\frac{\text{numerator}}\ \ \ \text{denominator is a space, two spaces follow the fraction, and text works} $$

**The trick is simple, every backslash is followed by a command, even if it is just a space, for a linebreak, the command is another backslash. Backslashes are treated in the order in which they are written (from the first to the last)**

I'm not sure of the termilogies I used or even my argument, so if anything is wrong, add your comment below.

Comment: Thanks ${ }$ ${ }$