# Where to report MathJax bugs?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, allowed-questions, meta

**TL;DR:** What is a suitable place where to report MathJax bugs?

I mean the bugs which seem to be issues with MathJax in general - not specific to this site or Stack Exchange network.

---

Often some issues with MathJax are reported on this meta. Sometimes it is not clear in advance whether it is MathJax-related bug or whether it is site specific. And in some cases when it turned out to be actually problem with MathJax, some members of the MathJax team who visit this site were able to forward the information to the correct place.

Also looking at the older discussion [Should we report LaTeX/MathJax issues in meta?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6725) I found 
[the following comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6725/should-we-report-latex-mathjax-issues-in-meta#comment23868_6725):
"Yes. Some of the MathJax developers roam around the meta site; and some of the bugs are due to faulty SE code. Both parties are roaming around this meta to find bug reports." Which basically confirms that the questions about MathJax problems are most likely ok here on this meta.

In any case, what should I do if I strongly suspect that it is an issue which is not site specific but it is indeed a bug in MathJax. (For example, if I see the same behavior also on other sites, which are outside Stack Exchange network.)

- Would it be still ok to post here? (Argument in favor of this is that as a user of this site I already know how to use this meta. To post somewhere else I might have to create account or some other site or learn to work with some other system. And considering that some MathJax developers follow this site, the information eventually gets to somebody who can do something about the problem.)
- Or should I usr some other site which is specifically devoted to MathJax? (And if this approach is preferable, what would be a reasonable place where to report such issues.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For those capable, perhaps the best place to post MathJax bugs is on the github issue tracker for MathJax. (Here is a link to the [Mathjax github](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax) page, and a link to their [issue tracker](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues)).

But for those who don't have or don't want to make github profiles, then I think posting it in the meta would be fine. A couple developers routinely check the site, and a couple occasional-developers-but-common-issue-reporters also peruse the site and forward on bugs to the issue list.

Comment: Yes, the GitHub issue tracker is definitely the first place to go. There's also a [MathJax user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users) which I think would be better than Meta.